# Capture SharePoint role group and group members?

Tags: 2007, development, security, .net

For our audit process I need to regularly capture all of our SharePoint role groups (for our main site collection) and the members in each group. Is there a reliable way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the powershell commands to write out each SPGroup (using [SPWeb.SiteGroups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.sitegroups.aspx)) and then writing out each member of the group.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using advice from Ryan Erickson, my proof (note: just a proof, hence sloppish standard code) is below (also not PowerShell as suggested since I'm more comfortable C# but it should be relatively easy to convert):

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;


namespace QIC.RE.SharePoint.Permissions.ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string siteCollection = "http://dev/re";

            string version = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Program)).GetName().Version.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] SharePoint Permissions started with version '{1}'.", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), version);

            try
            {
                using (var site = new SPSite(siteCollection))
                {
                    using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        foreach (SPGroup group in web.Groups)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\n[{0}] Group: '{1}'.", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), group.Name);
                            Console.WriteLine("###########################");

                            if (group.Users.Count > 0)
                            {
                                foreach (SPUser user in group.Users)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("\n[{0}] Username: '{1}'", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), user.Name);
                                    Console.WriteLine("\n[{0}] Login Name: '{1}'", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), user.LoginName);
                                    Console.WriteLine("\n[{0}] E-mail: '{1}'", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), user.Email);
                                    Console.WriteLine("\n[{0}] User ID: '{1}'", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), user.ID);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Group: '{1}' is empty.", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), group.Name);
                            }

                            Console.WriteLine("\n###########################");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Error: Unable to open site '{1}'.", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), siteCollection);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```